# "Keyboard" version of "trigger-happy"?

Tags: adjectives

What would be a good adjective to describe someone who sends/publishes digital artefacts without thought. For example: someone who likes participating in flame-wars, or someone who replies to an e-mail before prior thought (even if not rudely). In short, a "keyboard" version of "trigger-happy".

Comment: Keyboard warriors?

Comment: Nice! But I thought that term described people who are particularly brave online (owing to the pseudo-anonymity the internet provides us when interacting within it), but turn out to be tame/shy individuals in person.

Comment: Related: _[ohnosecond](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ohnosecond):_ the instant of time before hitting "send," and realising that you didn't mean to send it.

Answer (score 2):

I have three suggestions.  The first is ***digitally-incontinent***

**incontinent**, as defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incontinent):

> a (1): lacking self-restraint (2): not being under control
>
> b: unable to retain urine or feces voluntarily

**Digitally-incontinent** would mean an inability to control one's fingers as they type and then send into the world message after message after message, not all of which are well-formed.  (Just realized double meaning of digital here, duh!)

See *Dealing with Digital Incontinence* at [Times Higher Education](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/news/tara-brabazon-dealing-with-digital-incontinence/415266.article)

Two variants on this are:

***keyboard incontinence*** and ***digital diarrhea***

The meaning of **incontinence** should be obvious from the definition of **incontinent** given above.  **Keyboard incontinence** means the same as **digital incontinence**.

My third suggestion is **digital diarrhea**, an extension of **verbal diarrhea**, which is defined by [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/verbal-diarrhoea) as

> to talk continuously or too much

Moreover **digital diarrhea** is defined by [The Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=digital%20diarrhea) as

> The social networking equivalent of verbal diarrhea.  Usually
>   involves an excessive amount of pointless quips on one's blog page,
>   facebook wall, twitter, etc.

The Urban Dictionary is not a highly regarded source on this site. But who can argue adapting verbal diarrhea as defined by Cambridge Dictionaries to digital diarrhea?

One would say: "John is digitally-incontinent" or "John has digital diarrhea" or "John has keyboard incontinence". The first is the same construction as "John is trigger happy"; the latter two are not, but but are close.  To a native English speaker these terms, although informal, are not nearly as impolite as the definitions of diarrhea and incontinence would suggest.

Comment: Although the reference to bodily functions makes me a little hesitant to use these phrases, I like this answer because of the examples of prior use.

Comment: @ArjunShankar I understand that.  One always has to consider how a word or phrase will sound among the people with whom one lives and works.  These phrases would be OK some places and not OK other places. I also considered "Loose cannon on the keyboard", from "loose cannon on deck", but the meaning wasn't right. [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/loose+cannon).

Answer (score 1):

You could call them a ***keyboard berserker***. I just made that up. It's a riff on *keyboard warrior*.

> **berserk**
>
> adjective
>   1. violently or destructively frenzied; wild; crazed; deranged:
>   *He suddenly went berserk.*
>
> noun
>   2. (*sometimes initial capital letter*) *Scandinavian Legend.*. Also, **berserker**. an ancient Norse warrior who fought with frenzied rage in battle, possibly induced by eating hallucinogenic mushrooms.
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/berserker)]

Comment: That's not bad at all!